# Suppressing the column classes for "tibbles"

Tags: r, tibble

How do you suppress the column classes when displaying tibbles? For example,

```
> cars <- as_tibble(mtcars)
> cars
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  # <-- I don't want to show this row
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Is there a global option? Something along the lines of `options("show.tibble.column.classes"=FALSE)`.

I'd also like to remove them for all output created from a tibble (tbl_df).

```
> count(cars, cyl)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>  # <-- omit this row totally.
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? Would changing it to dataframe not solve your issue?

Comment: @Ronak Shah. I like all the other features of the tibbles. But sometimes I don't want the column classes to be shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
cat(format(as_tibble(mtcars))[-3L], sep = "\n")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Explanations

`?tibble::print.tbl` shows that the class `tbl_df` is associated with the following `format` method:

```
Usage

## S3 method for class 'tbl_df'
format(x, ..., n = NULL, width = NULL, n_extra = NULL)
```

The `format` method converts a tibble into a character vector, each element of which is a line to be printed. The third line is for variable types. To get the desired output, we just need to remove that line and `cat()` the rest as is.